# How does beta+ decay actually occur?

Tags: atoms, neutrinos, radioactivity, protons, neutrons

I'm having difficulty in understanding [beta plus decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#.CE.B2.2B_decay). How can a proton which has slightly less mass than neutron transform into a neutron, positron and neutrino?

Form where does the extra mass for neutron,electron and neutrino come? 
Is it that during the decay some of the binding energy gets converted into mass?

Comment: Also of interest [β+ decay](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60357).

Comment: @dmckee Didn't find it while typing this question. Should I delete this question sir?

Comment: It is up to you, it won't be deleted by policy, because having different titles helps people to find the existing answered version better in the future (and as you said, the title of the other one is not the only way to ask the question).